# Reasons for nullpointer exception in jsp with msAccess database

Tags: java, jsp, nullpointerexception, ms-access-2007

a simple code to connect with MS Access db.
1) classpath,catalina_home,path, java_home all set.

2) created a db named "Actors" and put it in "java/jdk/bin" directory.

3) done with odbc connectivity in control panel

Now when i try to access the database i get "Nullpointer exception". Code is below,

```
<%@page import="java.io.*,java.sql.*" %>
<% try {  Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Actors"); 
} catch(Exception e){out.println(con);} %>
```

This is working code in my PC. But when i tried in my college PC(XP) it's not working even if the path are set;

**it prints  "null".**
So does any other problem is there which cause NullPointerException ?

Comment: Can you remove the try catch block and post the stack trace?

Comment: actually i did that program in college PC. i will get "stack trace" after 2 days. please wait.